# Can I use JsonEditor to edit JSON Schemas?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema

I've admired JSON-editor [1] for a long time, and am quite familiar with using it to edit a document based upon a JSON schema for that document.

Why? A body of users edit JSON documents, using JSON-Editor, according to the relevant schema for that document type.  That works fine.

I now wish to enable one or more power users to be able to create new document definitions - developing those definitions (json-schemas) using JSON-Editor.  (Clearly a useful feature will be to display a "preview" of what an editor for that document-type will look like)

Has anyone tried to use JSON-editor to create/ edit the Schema's themselves?  For this to happen there would initially have to be a JSON-schema describing the allowable structure for a JSON-Schema (note: possibly this: [2])

[1] https://github.com/json-editor/json-editor

[2] https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/blob/master/schema.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second link you included in your question is what's called the meta-schema.

The meta-schema, is as you've idenified, a JSON Schema for JSON Schema documents.

Given draft-8 isn't published yet, you probably want tme meta-schema for draft-7, which is located at https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/blob/draft-handrews-json-schema-01/schema.json

Comment: This of course brings us to the question, where is the meta-meta-schema?

Comment: Given the meta-schema is a JSON Schema, it is also its own meta-schema... =D

Comment: So it's schemas all the way down? :)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying thst, @Relequestual.  When I provide the meta-schema to the JSON editor, the UI won't let me create an element.

I suspect I need to produce a reduced schema. After all, the editor would only need to implement the parts of the JSON schema that JSON-Editor uses to config it's graphical editor - which is probably a small subset.